# What can resolve my hardware issues with linux 3.11.0-15 in Saucy Salimander?

Tags: 13.10, kernel

Okay, newb here, so be a bit gentle, please. I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 over my 12.04 LTS partion (saving home folder) and booted it up to discover my cursor had disappeared, my mouse touchpad undetected, my graphic acceleration reduced greatly, my processor running at full 100 percent load, and everything sluggishly crawling, which is a far cry from the beauty linux and Ubuntu has proven to be in the past.

i restarted, then from the advanced settings in grub, selected Ubuntu with Linux 3.11.0-12 from the menu and it worked like a charm! So now, how can i either set this kernel to boot defaultly or fix the errors with the newer kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if you think it's a kernel issue then open a Terminal window and enter these commands:

```
cd /tmp

wget http://goo.gl/kOhnhZ -O kernel-3.13.3

chmod +x kernel-3.13.3

sudo sh kernel-3.13.3

sudo reboot
```

...after reboot you will be using the new 3.13.3 which has had a lot of improvements for your ati chipsets and graphics, hopefully it will help...

Comment: 4gb ram,  amd turion processor, ati radeon hd 4200 gpu

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that tonight. Just in case I can't get to the terminal or the web (that has been one of the issues, network drivers weren't starting) how can I do this from a Live USB Disk?

Comment: Pressing CTRL + ALT + T should open a terminal window for you also, failing that, returning to one of the tty screens by typing CTRL + ALT + F1 (F7 returns to desktop)...